# How to fix nan in anonymous function?

Tags: matlab, nan, anonymous-function

Suppose I have a function `f(x)` defined, which gives `nan` when it is very large, say `x>100`. Fortunately, when `x>100`, I can replace `f` by another function `g`. So I would like to define:

```
h = @(x)isnan(f(x)).*f(x)+isnan(f(x)).*g(x)
```

However, when I substitute `h(1001)`, it gives `nan`. Is it possible to define `h` so that it gives `g(1001)` instead of `nan`? The only restriction is that I need to have anonymous function `h` for later use, say I would like to use it in integration, i.e., `integral(h,0,inf)`.

Example: Suppose I have a function:

```
f = @(x)x.*1./x
```

This function is very easy and must be `1`. I construct a function:

```
g = @(x)isnan(f(x)).*0+isnan(f(x)).*1
```

How to make `g` to be well defined so that I can still evaluate `integral(g,-1,1)`? For this example, I know I can evaluate it easily, but my restriction is that I need to define anonymous function `g` and use integral to do it.

Comment: You would be much better off making a non-anonymous function. Any reason why you want it to be anonymous? Also please see this: https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/168998-defining-anonymous-function-using-an-if-statement

Comment: 3this is because i need to use integral to do evaluation.

Comment: There is no need for anonymous functions in `integral`. You need a function handle, it can be a handle to any function, including one defined in a file or a sub-function. You can pass `@my_func` as argument to use a function called `my_func`.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make a regular function and wrap it with the anonymous function.

i.e.

```
function r = ternary(a, b, c)
  if (a)
    r = b;
  else
    r = c;
  end
end

h = @(x)ternary(isnan(f(x)), g(x), f(x));
```

Note that this will evaluate your function twice. A less generalized solution for your particular case that won't evaluate the function twice.

```
function r = avoidNAN(a, b)
  if (isnan(a))
    r = b;
  else
    r = a;
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks. i have not think of doing this. any better than this solution?

Comment: Not that i can think of, there's no real downside to the second answer in your case.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution without any additional functions:

```
f = @(x)x.*1./x;
g = @(x)100+x;
h= @(x)getfield(struct('a',f(x),'b',g(x)),char(isnan(f(x))+'a'))
```